# Problem to find steady state when I assume Y=1

Tags: macroeconomics, dsge, steady-state

I am trying to do a DSGE model in Matlab, I have all the steady state equations on paper and pencil but I fail to find values for all variables.

Indeed, since I have constant return to scale, [image]  I have then tried to assume Y=1 to simplify the calculations. But it leads me to a problem:

My market clearing equation is okay: all sums to 1 at steady state. [image]

However the production function does not equal to 1. It's because I have used other equations to determine N, N prime and wages. I used these equations to determine N, N ', w and w':

[image]

I have tried to use the production function, make Y=1, and since I know K I can express N in function of N '.

[image]

Where Y=A=1 and K is known

But then I fail at finding on paper and pencil a value for N, N prime and w and w'

Do you have an idea how can I assume Y=1 and still have the market clearing and the production function equal to 1 ? Do you recommand me another way to solve my steady states ?